# How to count unique strings in bash and list

Tags: bash, text, text-processing

I have a [csv](https://codeshare.io/ejKZk) file, how can I count a given field (field #2), for unique strings and then list all the unique strings with the frequency next to it with bash script?

Ideally I would like to see a print out of all the unique strings that appeared in the second field, and the number of times they have appeared with bash?

Comment: `man awk`.  What have you tried so far, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a very simple CSV:

```
awk -F, '{a[$2]++}END{for(i in a)print i": "a[i]}' < file
```

Since there is no standard Unix tool I know of that can read CSV properly, for more complex CSV files you need a higher programming language:

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'a = Hash.new(0); STDIN.each_line { |l| a[CSV.parse(l)[0][1]] += 1 }; a.each { |k, v| puts "#{k}: #{v}" }' < file
```